# Output video to both file and pipe: simultaneously using FFmpeg Libav

Tags: c, ffmpeg, pipe, frame-rate, libav

I have been trying to output video (from my webcam) simultaneously to both a file ('out.mkv') and pipe:
The file gets filtered frames, and the pipe: gets unfiltered rawvideo.
My frame rate is 30 fps. However, I am getting a far lower framerate in my file output.

Attached is the while loop which reads packets and writes them to output:

```
while (1) {
    av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, packet);
    stream_index = packet->stream_index;
    StreamContext *stream = &file_stream_ctx[stream_index];
    av_packet_rescale_ts(packet,
                     ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base,
                     stream->dec_ctx->time_base);
    avcodec_send_packet(stream->dec_ctx, packet);

    while (ret >= 0) {
        avcodec_receive_frame(stream->dec_ctx, stream->dec_frame);
        stream->dec_frame->pts = stream->dec_frame->best_effort_timestamp;
        ret = filter_encode_write_frame(stream->dec_frame, stream_index,file_stream_ctx,file_filter_ctx, file_ofmt_ctx);
        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(pipe_ofmt_ctx, packet);
    }
}
```

'ifmt_ctx' is the AVFormatContext for the webcam.
'file_ofmt_ctx', is the AVFormatContext for the pipe for the output file, and pipe_ofmt_ctx is the AVFormatContext.
'file_stream_ctx' and 'file_filter_ctx' are the stream and filter contexts used for filtering and encoding the file output.

My guess is that writing to the pipe is taking too long and not allowing the next packet to be read on time - causing a lower frame rate. Does that make sense? If so - any suggestions on how to fix it? (I tried using AVFMT_FLAG_NONBLOCK but it doesn't seem to help).

Thanks
Hillel

Comment: Does your console output when you run this complain about missing packets / dropped packets?  I typically see those warnings from the library when packets are being dropped because I can't consume them in time.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without any profiling, but you're probably correct given what you're seeing.  I'd be curious to know if you eliminate one of the write outs if you see better performance.

I always write the packets or frames (depending on the case) into a queue and have a separate thread do writing.  You might even want two threads - one for the video (packet queue) and one for the frames.

As an aside, I think the line `avcodec_send_packet(stream->dec_ctx, packet);` consumes the packet, so when you use it later in `ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(pipe_ofmt_ctx, packet);` that seems like it wouldn't work.  You could try copying the packet and see if that helps at all:

`av_packet_ref(new_packet, packet);`

Assuming you've allocated new_packet of course.  Doesn't sound like what your seeing is this, so it might be OK what you're doing.  But something you could also try.